# Come duplicates in list of items?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been working on this hackerrank challenge for a hell of a long time now and I can't seem to figure it out.

I've been able to get up to a part where I sort a bunch of information but I'm having trouble understanding how to combine a few things

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ILfu.png]

As you can see, I have a duplicate in the "Your Output" box with the date 2015-12. How can I go about combing them to get something like the "Expected Output"?

Thanks!

This is the code I've written so far

```
from datetime import date
from collections import Counter

line = input()

startDate = line.split(',')[0]
startYear, startMonth = startDate.split('-')
startDate = date(int(startYear), int(startMonth), 1)

endDate = line.split(' ')[1]
endYear, endMonth = endDate.split('-')
endDate = date(int(endYear), int(endMonth), 1)

line = input()

d =[]
while True:
    try:
        line = input()
        currentDate = date(int(line.split('-')[0]), int(line.split('-')[1].split('-')[0]), 1)

        if startDate <= currentDate < endDate:
            engagement = line.split(',')[1].strip()
            totalEngage = line.split(',')[2].strip()
            correctDate = "{}-{}".format(currentDate.year, str(currentDate.month).zfill(2))
            d.append([correctDate,engagement, totalEngage])
    except:
        break

d.sort(reverse=True)

print(d)
```

Comment: create a dict (key,value) key is your date, value is [] of values.

Comment: The duplication is absolutely incorrect